# Errorin installing mlxtend package in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

C:\Users\UTKARSH>conda install -c conda-forge mlxtend
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2

added / updated specs:
    - mlxtend

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
mlxtend: 0.13.0-py_1      conda-forge
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
certifi: 2018.4.16-py27_0             --> 2018.4.16-py27_0 conda-forge
conda:   4.5.4-py27_0                 --> 4.5.11-py27_0    conda-forge
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling packag
e 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py27_0'.
WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')

(base) C:\Users\UTKARSH>conda install -c conda-forge mlxtend
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2

added / updated specs:
    - mlxtend

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
mlxtend: 0.13.0-py_1      conda-forge
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
certifi: 2018.4.16-py27_0             --> 2018.4.16-py27_0 conda-forge
conda:   4.5.4-py27_0                 --> 4.5.11-py27_0    conda-forge
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling packag
e 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py27_0'.
WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')

Answer (score 1):

I got the exactly the same issue. 
I was able to fix the issue by doing below two things:

1. Run Windows Command as an Administrator (Refer to Import oct2py says access is denied )
2. Try this command in the Windows Command: `conda install mlxtend --channel conda-forge`

Comment: Solved my problem! Thanks for the answer.